# Android Studio 1.3, why aren't .so files included in my APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-library

I am new to Android Studio.  I am using Android Studio 1.3 because it has built in NDK support.  I have a project that can be used as an application or as a library project.  When I imported it to Android Studio as an application (and modified the gradle scipts as documented), it built the .so files and included them in the .apk output.  When I modified it to be a library project, it is building the .so files, but not including them in the .aar output and hence they are missing in the final .apk.  Should I have to do anything to inform it to put the .so files into the .aar?  If so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building your .so files by calling ndk-build or by using the gradle or gradle-experimental plugin ?

If your .so files are already built, you can just drop them inside *src/main/jniLibs/* folders and they should get included into the .aar as well as the APK.

Comment: They are being built using gradle-experimental just by running "Make Project".  I know I can do manual steps to make this work, but I was looking to see if there was some known modification to my gradle files that will get it to automatically include it in the .APK (which it does if the jni files are not within an added library).